# Invariant error in react native cannot find store

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile, redux, expo

i have been setting up redux for a react native application i have been working on for a few days. I keep getting invariant error could not find store in either the context or props. I have been googling it for days and tried multiple different solutions, but I cant seem to be able to fix this error.

Store:

```
`import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore,applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import combineReducers from "./reducers/combineReducers";
import App from './App'

const store = createStore(combineReducers ,applyMiddleware(thunk));

render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App/>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('App')
);`
```

The App component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';
import MainMenu from "./Components/MainMenu";
import {Root} from "native-base";
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {Font, AppLoading} from 'expo';

export class App extends Component {
    state = {
        loadingFont: true,
        testText:'Test'
    };

        async componentDidMount() {
            try {
                await Font.loadAsync({
                    'pixel-font': require('./assets/fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf'),
                });
                this.setState({loadingFont: false});

            }catch (e) {
                console.log(e)
            }
        }


    render() {
        if (this.state.loadingFont) {
            return (
                <Root>
                    <AppLoading/>
                </Root>
            );
        }
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <MainMenu/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {productions:state.productions}
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex:1,
        backgroundColor:'#fff',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
});
```

I know this is a question that has been asked quite a few times, but i feel Like I have browsed through all of the answers and found none that work. At this point I know that i have made an error somewhere, but after looking at this for a couple of days i have sort of gone blind to finding any solution on my own.

Comment: Can you post your full code? Or maybe make an Expo snack online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Export the store from your store file and import it to your App.js file. The Provider should also be in your App.js file wrapped around `<Root>`. Are you working in react-native? If so, you wouldn't use React-Dom, Expo will load the App.js file.

Comment: You got me on the right path. Expo is looking by default for App.js as the root, so if you use App.js for rendering the initial main menu and put your store in a different file not named App it will not work. I fixed it by renaming App js to Main and then i named the store file for App provider inside that around Main and it worked. You could in theory fix it by changing the import in expo's app entry file to whatever you want, but its easier to just use the original App.js that gets created when you create a react native app for the store. Thanks !